# Kendo Grid Date Picker Template date string format

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, grid

I am using a kendo grid with a date editor template.  I am trying to format date using the client template.

The current output is: 'Fri Jul 13 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)'.

How do I get it into 'yyyy-MM-dd' format?

below is the column code

```
columns.Bound(c => c.NewEffectiveDate)
   .ClientTemplate("#if(NewEffectiveDate === null){#  #}else{# #=kendo.toString(NewEffectiveDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')#  #}#")
   .EditorTemplateName("Date")
   .Title("New Effective Date")
   .Width(100)
   .HtmlAttributes(new
       {
          style = "text-align: center;"
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can u try

```
kendo.toString(new Date(2000, 10, 6), "d") -> 10/6/2000
```

We need to define the format specifier for particular pattern.

The "d" specifier renders a short date pattern ("M/d/yyyy" for en-US), as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I updated the code and the view is now formatted correctly but the post back to the controller is still not formatted.

Comment: In PostBack to controller what you are receiving??

Comment: Thu Jul 19 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)